# Quantifier elimination, subgroups of modules

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

A theory T has property M if the following holds: For A and B models of T, if A is a substructure of B then A is also an elementary substructure of B. I want to prove that if a theory admits Quantifier Elimination then it has property M.

Comment: The property is known as model completeness. This is not a research-level question, it belongs to math.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that substructures agree on quantifier-free truth.

If both $A$ and $B$ model $T$ and $T$ admits quantifier-elimination, then for any formula $\varphi(x)$, there is a quantifier-free assertion $\psi(x)$ that $T$ proves is equivalent to $\varphi(x)$. So $A\models \psi(a)$ if and only if $B\models \psi(a)$, since $\psi$ is quantifier-free. Since $\psi$ is equivalent to $\varphi$ in models of $T$, it follows that $A\models\varphi(a)$ if and only if $B\models\varphi(a)$, and this is what it means for $A$ to be an elementary substructure.